# I am using angular-websocket (third party) in my application. I have ngWebSocket in my Module. I am not able to resolve the dependency using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This is my Module:

```
(function () {
    "use strict"

    angular.module('App', ['ngWebSocket', 'ngRoute', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

}());
```

Comment: You will most likely have to mock 'ngWebSocket'

Comment: I have tried to mock the dependency as below : 
beforeEach(function(){
angular.mock.module('ngWebSocket', []);
})
but it is not working. Do u have any solution?

Comment: I think this might help: https://coderwall.com/p/4kldbq/angularjs-ngwebsocket-mock-feature.